# SQL To select based on overlapping times

Tags: t-sql

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question.  I've got a view with the start and end times of an event.  I want to know how many concurrent events there are.  Meaning over the past 7 days, how many events occurred at the same time, and generally what time that was.

```
SELECT dateCreated, dateEnded, ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                 FROM vw_LeadTime vw2 
                                 WHERE vw2.dateCreated >= vw.dateCreated 
                                 AND vw2.dateCreated <= vw.dateEnded )
                                 AS CountInTimePeriod
FROM vw_LeadTime vw
WHERE vw.dateEnded IS NOT NULL  
AND vw.dateCreated > '5/17/2011'
```

This is pretty ugly, but it appears to work.  Is there a cleaner (or faster) way to do this?  Am I making this too difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current sql only select events that are started during another event. You miss the one that started before another event but ended during or after it.
More correct would be:

```
SELECT dateCreated, dateEnded, ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                 FROM vw_LeadTime vw2 
                                 WHERE vw2.dateEnded >= vw.dateCreated 
                                 AND vw2.dateCreated <= vw.dateEnded )
                                 AS CountInTimePeriod
FROM vw_LeadTime vw
WHERE vw.dateEnded IS NOT NULL  
AND vw.dateCreated > '5/17/2011'
```

In general two periods A-B and C-D overlap when `A<=D AND B>=C`

Comment: Thanks -- that's not what I was looking for, but your answer was better than the question I was asking.  Stupid mistake.